# Pass class object to javascript context objective C

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a problem! Today I am developing an application in objective C which dialog with javascript and it look like this.

I have a UIWebview which I retrieve the context with JSContext and I pass an object to the context :

```
JSContext *context =  [self valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"]; // Undocumented access
context[@"classNameInJS"] = [[objCClass alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/page.html", path]];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Everything works fine but Apple reject my application because I use JSContext. 
So is there a another way to pass an object to javascript context ?

Answer (score 0):

theorically use JSContext dont has problem, but execute a downloaded script has. However, depends who will review your App in the Apple Review process. I dont know how another way tho pass a object to javascript context.

I made an app and to make this communication (objective-c <-> javascript) I call functions to javascript in objective-c and I do a redirect from javascript to objective-c.

```
//to call a javascript function from objective-c
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"javascriptFunction('%@')", parameter]];
```

To receive callback from javscript, I think the only way is with redirect passing the parameters in the URL, when the UIWebview receive the redirect, is dispatched the webView delegate shouldStartLoadWithRequest, then you get the parameters from request url and interrupt the load returning false

```
//webview delegate
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

To more information, you can read this links:

- http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/101540/Introduction-to-JavaScriptCore-Framework-in-iOS-Development
- http://perrymitchell.net/article/communication-between-javascript-ios-using-uiwebview-base64/

I hope this can help you. Good luck.